# Трехуровневое меню \ Псевдоклассы CSS

Tags: css, css3, html5

Добрый день уважаемые. Подскажите, пожалуйста как реализовать на CSS отображение трехуровневого меню Вот на этом примере

```css
/* MY MENU*/

.correct_right {
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}

.correct_left {
  padding-left: 0 !important;
}

.navigation_fluid {
  background-color: #00ab00;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.main-nav {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.main-nav__fullMenu {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  /*min-height: 50px;*/
}

.main-nav__item {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 50px;
  width: calc(100% / 7);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
}

.main-nav__item:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

.main-nav__link {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main-nav__name {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2% 1%;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}

.main-nav__name:hover {
  background-color: #53c205;
}

.main-nav__link:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.megamenu {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
  text-align: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.megamenu_wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.subCategories_name {
  display: table-cell;
  /*display: none;*/
  width: 185px;
  font-size: 14px;
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 16px;
}

.main-nav__item .main-nav__link:hover .subCategories_name {
  display: table-cell;
}

.subCategories_full {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 9px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.subCategories_item {
  width: 100%;
  display: list-item;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.subCategories_item:hover {
  color: #53c205;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.subCategories_view {
  display: none;
  /*display: flex;*/
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 30px 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 290px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.subCategories_looks {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  max-width: 100px;
}

.subCategories_looks__link {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 100px;
  /*border: 1px solid red;*/
}

.subCategories_looks__link:hover .subCategories_looks__name {
  color: #53c205;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.subCategories_looks__name {
  font-size: 13px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  color: #000;
}

.subCategories_looks__imageBlock {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.subCategories_looks__img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100px;
  background-size: cover;
}

.megamenu .megamenu_wrapper .subCategories_name .subCategories_full .subCategories_item:nth-of-type(1):hover .megamenu_wrapper .subCategories_view:nth-of-type(1),
.megamenu .megamenu_wrapper .subCategories_name .subCategories_full .subCategories_item:nth-of-type(2):hover .megamenu_wrapper .subCategories_view:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid navigation_fluid">
  <div class="container correct_right correct-left">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <nav id="menu" class="main-nav">
        <ul class="main-nav__fullMenu">
          <li class="main-nav__item">
            <a class="main-nav__link" href="#">
              <h2 class="main-nav__name">ROOT</h2>
            </a>
            <div class="megamenu">
              <div class="megamenu_wrapper">
                <div class="subCategories_name">
                  <ul class="subCategories_full">
                    <li class="subCategories_item">Игры, Мультимедиа</li>
                    <li class="subCategories_item">Ноутбуки</li>
                    <li class="subCategories_item">Планшеты</li>
                    <li class="subCategories_item">Электронные книги</li>
                    <li class="subCategories_item">Персональные Компьютеры</li>
                    <li class="subCategories_item">Принтеры</li>
                    <li class="subCategories_item">Сетевое Оборудование</li>
                    <li class="subCategories_item">Компьютерная периферия</li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <ul class="subCategories_view">
                  <li class="subCategories_looks">
                    <div class="subCategories_looks__item">
                      <a class="subCategories_looks__link" href="#">
                        <h3 class="subCategories_looks__name">Игровые приставки</h3>
                        <div class="subCategories_looks__imageBlock visible-md visible-lg">
                          <img class="subCategories_looks__img" src="/image/catalog/demo/1.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="subCategories_view">
                  <li class="subCategories_looks">
                    <div class="subCategories_looks__item">
                      <a class="subCategories_looks__link" href="#">
                        <h3 class="subCategories_looks__name">Acer</h3>
                        <div class="subCategories_looks__imageBlock visible-md visible-lg">
                          <img class="subCategories_looks__img" src="/image/catalog/demo/1.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="subCategories_looks">
                    <div class="subCategories_looks__item">
                      <a class="subCategories_looks__link" href="#">
                        <h3 class="subCategories_looks__name">Asus</h3>
                        <div class="subCategories_looks__imageBlock visible-md visible-lg">
                          <img class="subCategories_looks__img" src="/image/catalog/demo/1.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="subCategories_looks">
                    <div class="subCategories_looks__item">
                      <a class="subCategories_looks__link" href="#">
                        <h3 class="subCategories_looks__name">Dell</h3>
                        <div class="subCategories_looks__imageBlock visible-md visible-lg">
                          <img class="subCategories_looks__img" src="/image/catalog/demo/1.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="subCategories_looks">
                    <div class="subCategories_looks__item">
                      <a class="subCategories_looks__link" href="#">
                        <h3 class="subCategories_looks__name">Dream Machines</h3>
                        <div class="subCategories_looks__imageBlock visible-md visible-lg">
                          <img class="subCategories_looks__img" src="/image/catalog/demo/1.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="subCategories_looks">
                    <div class="subCategories_looks__item">
                      <a class="subCategories_looks__link" href="#">
                        <h3 class="subCategories_looks__name">Fujitsu</h3>
                        <div class="subCategories_looks__imageBlock visible-md visible-lg">
                          <img class="subCategories_looks__img" src="/image/catalog/demo/1.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="subCategories_looks">
                    <div class="subCategories_looks__item">
                      <a class="subCategories_looks__link" href="#">
                        <h3 class="subCategories_looks__name">HP</h3>
                        <div class="subCategories_looks__imageBlock visible-md visible-lg">
                          <img class="subCategories_looks__img" src="/image/catalog/demo/1.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="subCategories_looks">
                    <div class="subCategories_looks__item">
                      <a class="subCategories_looks__link" href="#">
                        <h3 class="subCategories_looks__name">Lenovo</h3>
                        <div class="subCategories_looks__imageBlock visible-md visible-lg">
                          <img class="subCategories_looks__img" src="/image/catalog/demo/1.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="subCategories_looks">
                    <div class="subCategories_looks__item">
                      <a class="subCategories_looks__link" href="#">
                        <h3 class="subCategories_looks__name">MSI</h3>
                        <div class="subCategories_looks__imageBlock visible-md visible-lg">
                          <img class="subCategories_looks__img" src="/image/catalog/demo/1.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="subCategories_looks">
                    <div class="subCategories_looks__item">
                      <a class="subCategories_looks__link" href="#">
                        <h3 class="subCategories_looks__name">Packard Bell</h3>
                        <div class="subCategories_looks__imageBlock visible-md visible-lg">
                          <img class="subCategories_looks__img" src="/image/catalog/demo/1.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="subCategories_looks">
                    <div class="subCategories_looks__item">
                      <a class="subCategories_looks__link" href="#">
                        <h3 class="subCategories_looks__name">Samsung</h3>
                        <div class="subCategories_looks__imageBlock visible-md visible-lg">
                          <img class="subCategories_looks__img" src="/image/catalog/demo/1.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="subCategories_looks">
                    <div class="subCategories_looks__item">
                      <a class="subCategories_looks__link" href="#">
                        <h3 class="subCategories_looks__name">Sony</h3>
                        <div class="subCategories_looks__imageBlock visible-md visible-lg">
                          <img class="subCategories_looks__img" src="/image/catalog/demo/1.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="subCategories_looks">
                    <div class="subCategories_looks__item">
                      <a class="subCategories_looks__link" href="#">
                        <h3 class="subCategories_looks__name">Toshiba</h3>
                        <div class="subCategories_looks__imageBlock visible-md visible-lg">
                          <img class="subCategories_looks__img" src="/image/catalog/demo/1.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="subCategories_looks">
                    <div class="subCategories_looks__item">
                      <a class="subCategories_looks__link" href="#">
                        <h3 class="subCategories_looks__name">Аксессуары для ноутбуков</h3>
                        <div class="subCategories_looks__imageBlock visible-md visible-lg">
                          <img class="subCategories_looks__img" src="/image/catalog/demo/1.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="subCategories_looks">
                    <div class="subCategories_looks__item">
                      <a class="subCategories_looks__link" href="#">
                        <h3 class="subCategories_looks__name">Коплектующие для ноутбука</h3>
                        <div class="subCategories_looks__imageBlock visible-md visible-lg">
                          <img class="subCategories_looks__img" src="/image/catalog/demo/1.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="subCategories_looks">
                    <div class="subCategories_looks__item">
                      <a class="subCategories_looks__link" href="#">
                        <h3 class="subCategories_looks__name">Apple</h3>
                        <div class="subCategories_looks__imageBlock visible-md visible-lg">
                          <img class="subCategories_looks__img" src="/image/catalog/demo/1.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                </ul>




              </div>
            </div>


          </li>
          <li class="main-nav__item">
            <a class="main-nav__link" href="#">
              <h2 class="main-nav__name">
                Компьютеры и сети
              </h2>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="main-nav__item">
            <a class="main-nav__link" href="#">
              <h2 class="main-nav__name">
                ТВ, Аудио, Фото, Видео
              </h2>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="main-nav__item">
            <a class="main-nav__link" href="#">
              <h2 class="main-nav__name">
                Мобильная связь
              </h2>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="main-nav__item">
            <a class="main-nav__link" href="#">
              <h2 class="main-nav__name">
                Туризм, Спорт, Отдых
              </h2>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="main-nav__item">
            <a class="main-nav__link" href="#">
              <h2 class="main-nav__name">
                Для детей
              </h2>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="main-nav__item">
            <a class="main-nav__link" href="#">
              <h2 class="main-nav__name">
                Бытовая техника
              </h2>
            </a>
          </li>


        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9h5sbye7/1/
Я немогу понять почему не отрабатывает последняя строка моего CSS ? Как сделать плавное отображение Навел на слово Игры, Мультимедиа получил блок с Игровые приставки навел на Ноутбуки получил блок с марками ноутбуков

Answer (score 1):

Всё на самом деле очень даже просто. Обычное наследование в CSS.  Вот написал простенький примерчик. В твоём коде всё слишком сложно и грустно, так не делается

---

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Menu</title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul class="main-menu">
    <li class="main-list">Menu 1
      <ul class="second-menu">
        <li class="second-list">Second
          <ul class="third-menu">
            <li class="third-list">Third</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="second-list">Second
          <ul class="third-menu">
            <li class="third-list">Third</li>
            <li class="third-list">Third</li>
            <li class="third-list">Third</li>
            <li class="third-list">Third</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="main-list">Menu 2
      <ul class="second-menu">
        <li class="second-list">Second
          <ul class="third-menu">
            <li class="third-list">Third</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="second-list">Second
          <ul class="third-menu">
            <li class="third-list">Third</li>
            <li class="third-list">Third</li>
            <li class="third-list">Third</li>
            <li class="third-list">Third</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="main-list">Menu 3</li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**CSS**

```
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.main-menu{
  width:500px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:#444;
  display:flex;
  list-style:none;
  font-family:arial;
  color:#eee;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin:auto;
}
.main-menu > .main-list{
  line-height:50px;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.main-menu > .main-list:hover{
  background-color:#eee;
  color:#555;
}
.main-menu > .main-list > .second-menu{
  display:none;
  list-style:none;
}
.main-menu > .main-list:hover > .second-menu{
  display:block;
}
.main-menu > .main-list > .second-menu > .second-list:hover{
  background-color:#ddd;
}
.main-menu > .main-list > .second-menu > .second-list{
  height:50px;
  background-color:#eee;
}
.main-menu > .main-list > .second-menu > .second-list > .third-menu{
  display:none;
  margin-left:100%;
  margin-top:-50px;
  list-style:none;
  color:#eee;
}
.main-menu > .main-list > .second-menu > .second-list > .third-menu > .third-list{
  text-align:center;
  width: 150px;
  background-color:#777;
}
.main-menu > .main-list > .second-menu > .second-list > .third-menu > .third-list:hover{
  background-color:#566
}
.main-menu > .main-list > .second-menu > .second-list:hover > .third-menu{
  display:block;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Придумывать веросипед не нужно, есть масса готовых пимеров, достаточно погуглить. Вот неплохой пример http://variable.pp.ua/%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E-jquery-css/, наслаждайтесь:)

Comment: ссылка не рабочая

Comment: теперь работает